# Dev Console jumpy on mouse scroll

Tags: developer-console, scrolling

Since yesterday my dev console is jumpy when I scroll with the mouse wheel.

I use windows on chrome at 80% zoom default. Putting it back to 100% zoom does not fix the problem.

I only have this problem in the Salesforce Developer Console (and by extension Salesforce) and does not occur on any other websites.

Does anyone knows why is this happening? Thank you!

RESPONSE FROM SALESFORCE SUPPORT: We have reached out to R & D about this issue and they are actively working on it. As of now, a possible work around for this issue is to use Firefox as this seems to be happening only in chrome.
Also, we currently do not have an ETA on the fix or a Known issue link. But in the near future, if you want an update regarding the issue, you can log a case with us by referring the investigation:- "W-3697984"

Comment: Been happening to me on mac for over a year. Get to the end of the log and unable to scroll to the end as it jumps back up. Have to load the text version of the log to see the last bit 20-30 lines or so. Just another reason I rarely use dev console lol especially with tools like IC and IntelliJ

Comment: I love Dev Console! Been using it for 80% of development in recent months.

However, I recently started experiencing this scroll jumping behavior on Chrome v56 for Mac. The experience got so unbearable that I've switched to Firefox to continue using Dev Console.

Hope someone at SFDC figures out the cause!

Comment: Started for me today after I restarted my machine after about a week.   Quite annoying.

Comment: On top of this problem, the developer console has been crashing regularly for me the past few weeks in Chrome. I guess i'll use Firefox for now.

Comment: I have the same issue. It just started happening recently, been using Developer Console for past year as my primary IDE and it has worked ok. Now I can't get any work done due to this in Chrome. I'll look at another browser but very frustrating as I have Chrome configured for all my workloads.

Comment: This started happening to me today as well, and after a machine restart.  Super annoying.

Comment: The known issue has been created: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gTYQAY

Comment: enter chrome://flags into the address bar then search for the setting: Scroll Anchoring, and disable it.  Worked for me.

Comment: Chris, you should make it an answer.

Comment: Can't make it an answer someone closed the question.  I hope it does work for everyone though.  This was so frustrating.

Comment: Thank you Chris! It worked for me as well! This bug was driving me insane!

Comment: According to the known issue it should be fixed in the latest chrome version.

Comment: @ChrisMullins would you mind still making that into an answer ? I've reopened the question.

Comment: Someone else made an answer for it, with images, looks good to me. You can go ahead and accept that.  Not in it for the points.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Go to chrome://flags/#enable-scroll-anchoring the highlighted option is **Scroll Anchoring** disable it.

Now you will see the message "Your changes will take effect the next time you relaunch Google Chrome." in the bottom with a button **RELAUNCH NOW**, When you hit this button chrome will relaunch. So first save all your work and then hit this button.

[image: Disable Scroll Anchoring in chrome]

Credit: [@ChrisMullins](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157863/dev-console-jumpy-on-mouse-scroll/166406?#comment245974_157863)

Comment: I can confirm that this has fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This also works for the Opera browser with the following `opera:flags#enable-scroll-anchoring`

Comment: Chrome v68 - problem is back and now they have "Scroll Anchor Serialization" - no setting prevents the jumpy behavior. Ugh.

Comment: As of Dec 2019, There is no Scroll Anchor https://prnt.sc/q8d9e1  Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 13):

There is a Known Issue for this - [Developer Console jumping when using mouse scroll](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gTYQAY)

> **Summary**
>   When working in any piece of code in the Developer Console (apex class, lightning component, trigger and so on) if the user start scrolling down through the content of the piece of code using a mouse wheel, the screen starts scrolling, but then the view intermittently jumps in the opposite direction a few lines.

The current indication is that this is resolved by updating Chrome to v57. However, I've seen reports that this is still an issue even after updating to the latest version of Chrome.

There is a proposed workaround by [Chris Mullins](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157863/dev-console-jumpy-on-mouse-scroll/166406?#comment245974_157863) (which will hopefully be posted as a separate answer soon).

**UPDATE:** The issue is back in review status as the problem is still occurring for some users with v57 of Chrome. Since it is in review you can indicate that it is affecting you.

Comment: Yeah, I'm running Chrome 58 and still notice this issue. EDIT - just read the comments on the OP. Trying out the fix there...