# developer console browser freeze

Tags: apex, developer-console, bug

I have a quite long apex class almost 4000 LOC.

I do development on eclipse and deploy, but if I open this in developer console and try to edit few thing, scroll up and down a little bit, the browser get freeze.

Is this a problem with the browser or console it self?

Is there a way to stop/avoid this?

Comment: Did you try different browsers? Does this happen with 1 only, if so which one?

Comment: Potential duplicate of [Dev Console jumpy on mouse scroll](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/157863/102). Is it limited to the mouse scroll wheel? I've heard reports of the bug regressing recently.

Comment: Note that the associated patch to fix the issue isn't fully deployed yet - [Developer Console jumping when using mouse scroll](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gTYQAY)

Comment: Sounds like a good time to break up the class....